# Function that receives a character, checks if is character and changes ti ascii code

Tags: vba, char

I want to write a function that receives a character (as a string), and returns the ascii code (as integer) for that character. This function will **not** assume that the string it received is in fact a character and not the ascii code already, so it needs to check this.

If the function **detects** the string as an ascii code of a character, the function should return that same string as an integer. (Unless the string is ascii code for a whitespace character or invalid ascii code. If so the function should throw an error.)

If the function **detects** the string as a character, the function should return the ascii code. (Unless there are a few characters in the string. If so the function should throw an error.)

I realize that this may not be possible, But please try to answer this if you have any ideas. I want an answer either in vba code or pseudo code.

Comment: What did you try to solve it on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "if isnumeric" to check if it is a number. If you want to check if any part is number you can split the string into any number of parts and check each for isnumeric. If the check does not resolve (If there's many checks you might want to use a flag) then you can do asc(*string) to get the ascii-value of the string.
If you want to check for each single letter in a string you could do

```
for i = 1 to len(string)
if isnumeric(left(right(string,i),1)) then
numericflag = true
endif
next i
if numericflag = true then
'do something to resolve the error
else
output = asc(string)
endif
```

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here. I know already about vba functions IsNumeric and Asc which deal nicely with changing a char to ascii. But what I want is a **smart** function which gets only a string and can **tell** if I want it to be changed from char to ascii or if it is a number, to be returned as the ascii. So what is wrong with IsNumeric? here is an example: There is a character '9' and there is a character in the ninth position in the char table. Maybe the user wanted the ascii code for '9' or maybe he wants the ascii code 9.

Comment: Either there is a way to tell them apart or there is not. If sometimes you want 9 as string to be handled as number and sometimes you want 9 as string to be handled as string, then I guess you add an input for the user. Like an extra column that states wether something is a number or not or an input box that asks the user how to handle the situation everytime the function encounters something that could be a number. Or you could closer specify what numbers look like and what strings look like, but it's hard to guess that specification from here.

Answer (score 0):

- This function assumes that no whitespaces(backspace, tabs etc.) besides SPACE are allowed.

Receives a string. This string may be a character for which the user wishes to know the ascii code, or an ascii code which the user wishes to be turned into an integer.

```
Public Function CharToAscii(ByVal char As String) As Integer
    Dim ascii As Integer    'the variable that will be returned
    If Len(char) = 0 Then   'if empty string was sent...
        MsgBox "You sent an empty string" '...raise error
        GoTo errFunction
    ElseIf Len(char) > 1 Then   'if char is longer than one character...
        If IsNumeric(char) Then '...if the string is a number, assumed to be ascii code and...
            Select Case CInt(char)
                Case 0 To 31, 127 '...if the number is whitespace in ascii, raise error
                    MsgBox "You have entered a string of numbers." & Chr(10) & _
                    "We assumed you meant to get this string as a ascii code, but this string is code for a whitespace."
                    GoTo errFunction
                Case Is < 0, Is > 127 '...if the number does not exist in ascii, raise error
                    MsgBox "You have entered a string of numbers." & Chr(10) & _
                    "We assumed you meant to get this string as a ascii code, But there is no character for this number."
                    GoTo errFunction
            End Select
            ascii = CInt(char) '...if no error was raise,the number is OK, so return it
        Else                '...if the string is characters...
            MsgBox "you have sent more than one character. We assume you meant the first."
            Select Case Asc(char) '...check the ascii code for whitespace and...
                Case 0 To 31, 127 '...if whitespace, raise error
                    MsgBox "But it was a whitespace."
                    GoTo errFunction
            End Select      'if no error was raised, the number is okay
            ascii = Asc(char) 'asc() returns the ascii for the first character in a string.
        End If
    Else                    ' if only one character was received...
        Select Case Asc(char)
            Case 0 To 31, 127 '...if it is a whitespace, raise error
                MsgBox "You have entered a whitespace."
                GoTo errFunction
        End Select
        ascii = Asc(char)   '...if not return it
    End If
    CharToAscii = ascii
    GoTo finish
errFunction:
    MsgBox "please try again" 'or anything else you want to do in case of error
finish:
End Function
```

**Note:** wherever there is a message box, it means there was an error. You should change the `msgbox` to code that handles the error the way **you** want.